# How to protect my site user file from a website downloader

Tags: web

Hi suppose my site as [www.xyz.com](http://mysite.com) and i have a folder as _Userfile which have file uploaded by my users and if they download there file the link is [www.xyz/_Userfile/userfile.doc](http://www.mysite/_Userfile/userfile.doc) now i want to learn this:

1. if some one has the link to other user file he can download it i want to solve this(privacy)

2: protect my site file from website downloader.
ASAP plz

Also i am using virtual directory to save my user files so i need a way to protect any type of file to be downloaded by any kind of software

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement an authentication mechanism, and to serve those files through a server-side application (in PHP, Java or whatever), that checks if the authenticated user has the right to access a resource, then reads the resource from the disk and writes it to the HTTP response. The documents should be placed in a location that is not directly accessible through HTTP.

Answer (score -1):

Just add index.html file in the folder _Userfile... This will prevent others accessing the whole directory listing in _UserFile folder! Simple isn't it?

Comment: He cant keep guessing the file names!

Comment: ya i can change the file name at th time of upload but what about website downloader it can download the whole _userfile folder isn't it

Comment: the directory listing is not the problem as it a virtual dir so server dinies listing but i want another way to protect it may be password protected dir will help lets see